# Reconfigure Windows/Linux Dual Boot after Linux partition move

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, multi-boot

I had Windows and Linux (Ubuntu) set up on different partitions with dual-boot configured and everything worked fine.

I wanted to move just the Linux partition (the OS, files, etc.) to a different machine with Windows already installed, and set up dual boot there.

So on this machine, I created a partition to hold Linux, then copied partition *data* over from the first computer (using MiniTool Partition) onto this new partition.

Is there a way to configure the boot process on the new machine to show the purple screen prompt again, and allow normal dual-boot?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends. Theoretically possible even if using different boot modes (UEFI Vs Legacy) but the amount of work cannot be justified. Better to just backup the personal files and install fresh in the other pc. Much faster, simpler and more reliable.

Comment: I considered it, but did not go with it... until now, after discovering apt-clone (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208047/how-do-i-transfer-installed-packages-and-settings-from-one-distro-to-another/). Now a new install makes a lot more sense. Thanks!